# How do I deal with a column in Pandas that equals "NA"?

Tags: python, pandas

I know this sounds dumb, but I can't figure out what to do about data in a spreadsheet that equals "NA" (in my case, it's an abbreviation for "North America"). When I do a Pandas "read_excel", the data gets brought in as "NaN" instead of "NA".

Is "NA" also considered "Not a Number" like NaN is?

The input Excel sheet cells contain NA. The dataframe contains "NaN".

Any way to avoid this?

Comment: Do you have actual NaN values? I mean in addition to the  NA("North America") values. If you don´t, you could try df.fillna("NA").

Comment: No, not at this point. I can /probably/ assume that there won't be any, but I was hoping for some sort of generalized answer. For sure fillna would work if I didn't. I was hoping there was some way to coax Pandas to allow "NA" to flow through as data.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Comment: Yes. keep_default_na worked.  I missed that in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

You can **switch-off** auto-detection of `na-values` by using `keep_defaul_na=False` in `pandas.read_excel()` as follows.

> I am using the demo `test.xlsx` file that I created in the **Dummy Data** section.

```py
pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', keep_default_na=False)

## Output
#   Region    Country
# 0     NA     Canada
# 1     NA        USA
# 2     SA     Brazil
# 3     EU     Sweden
# 4     AU  Australia
```

### Dummy Data

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a dummy dataframe for demo purpose
df = pd.DataFrame({'Region': ['NA', 'NA', 'SA', 'EU', 'AU'], 
                   'Country': ['Canada', 'USA', 'Brazil', 'Sweden', 'Australia']})

# Create an excel file with this data
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False)

# Show dataframe
print(df)
```

**Output**

```sh
  Region    Country
0     NA     Canada
1     NA        USA
2     SA     Brazil
3     EU     Sweden
4     AU  Australia
```

Comment: keep_default_na=False worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @BillThelTGeek Please consider **accepting** the solution. Thank you.